# Update BigTable row in Apache Beam (Scio)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable, spotify-scio

I have the following use case:

There is a PubSub topic with data I want to aggregate using Scio and then save those aggregates into BigTable.

In my pipeline there is a `CountByKey` aggregation. What I would like to do is to be able to **increment value** in BigTable for a given key, preferably using `ReadModifyWrite`. In the `scio-examples` there are only updates related to setting column values but there are none of using atomic increment.

I uderstand that I need to create `Mutation` in order to perform any operation on BigTable, like this:

```
Mutations.newSetCell(
      FAMILY_NAME, COLUMN_QUALIFIER, ByteString.copyFromUtf8(value.toString), 0L)
```

How to create **UPDATE** mutation from Scio / Apache Beam transform to atomically update row in BigTable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything like `ReadModifyWrite` under `com.google.bigtable.v2.Mutation` API so not sure if this is possible. I see 2 possible workarounds:

- save events as a Pubsub topic, consume it from a backend service and increment there
- use a raw Bigtable client in a custom `DoFn`, see [`BigtableDoFn`](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/scio-bigtable/src/main/java/com/spotify/scio/bigtable/BigtableDoFn.java) for inspiration.